# Desktop Display shows as laptop and resolution mismatch with monitor

Tags: resolution

I have been using Ubuntu 12.04 without problem. After upgrading to 12.10 then 13.04, the display is messed up: under the setting, Displays setting shows as laptop, detection display button does not work, I can not change the resolution either. I am using a monitor with 1600x900 but the resolution in displays is set as 1280x1080. I have tried to reinstall the Ubuntu from CD, the problem is the same. I tried to install Ubuntu 13.04 on a new partition, then, the displays work ok. Anyone have idea how to fix this? Thanks a lot. Here is the output from the command below:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 vga

01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS780L [Radeon 3000] [1002:9616]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8388]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8P67 and other motherboards [1043:8432]
```

The output from xrandr is:

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 400, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024       0.0* 
   1152x864        0.0
   1024x768        0.0
   800x600         0.0
   640x480         0.0
   720x400         0.0

Comment: And what is `xrandr` output?

Comment: Thanks. The output from xrandr shows as below:  xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 400, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024       0.0* 
   1152x864        0.0  
   1024x768        0.0  
   800x600         0.0  
   640x480         0.0  
   720x400         0.0

Answer (score 0):

my.friend.
first login by recovery mode or nomodeset ( is best ) .
nomodeset :
after see grub press shift key or e key . find quiet splash and write nomodeset , after or befor quiet splash . dont forget space between. press f10 or ctrl+x to login .
after login you first install linux-source and linux-header :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers

sudo apt-get install linux-source .
```

after it install good driver to fix . test it from additional driver .

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried this, but seems not working. The display is still the same.